# modeless window to behave like a modal window using javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, internet-explorer

I have a requirement to have some modal popups appear on a webpage. At first i implemented them as true modal windows, but then i found out that true modal windows cannot communicate with parent window in IE.

Now i am trying to implement them as regular windows that always steal focus, which is sorta working.

Here is the code that i am using:

```
modalPopup = window.open(url, 'popup', arr.join(",")); //use a global var here
modalPopup.focus();

$(window).bind("focus.modal", function(){
  if(modalPopup){
    modalPopup.focus();
  } else {
    $(window).unbind("focus.modal");
  }
});
```

There are several things wrong with this:

1. In firefox, once i close the popup, the modalPopup does not become null, it points to parent window. (this is ok, since we dont support firefox anyway)
2. In IE, it works like a charm when you open 1 window and close it, but opening any more windows results in the exception:

   Error: The callee (server [not server application]) is not available and disappeared; all connections are invalid. The call did not execute.

**edit**: In IE the error happens when modalPopup.focus(); is called. apparently modalPopup is never set to a falsy value when closed :P

Can you help me write a better implementation that uses window.open for creating the popups?

Before anyone says anything, using lightbox **is not an option**. The popup windows contain A TON of html, javascript etc, and loading them in the DOM is not going to result in a good UX. Also, we sorta have to have this work on IE6.

Comment: i need to make my modeless window behave like a modal window

Comment: You're probably right, becouse the bound event function keeps its valiable table even after the modal is closed or set to a new value, doesn't it?

Comment: Modal windows can communicate with parent window.  See self.returnValue.

Comment: Josh: you are correct sir. You should make an actual answer so i can mark this answered.

Comment: It seems it would be simpler to overcome the problems you listed with divs instead of the problems with attempting browsers windows to behave reliably as multiple window applications, or am I missing something? Lightbox and other libraries may certainly be overkill for you.

Comment: Using a div with an iframe is certainly a solution to this problem in general, but not to my problem. What makes my problem different is that i dont have time to do this the 'good' way. Josh's solution works wonderfully for me here and i am happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The windows containing a "ton" of JavaScript, HTML, etc. isn't a reason that you can't use "lightbox" style techniques (which do work on IE6; I don't know if a specific library you've looked at doesn't). The technique is simple:

- Have an absolutely-positioned `iframe` on the page whose z-index is higher than any other content normally shown on the page. Normally the `iframe` is hidden.
- When doing a "modal," show that `iframe` and set it to cover all other content. Create an absolutely-positioned `div` with a higher z-index than the `iframe` and place it wherever you want (typically in the middle of the viewport).
- Put your "modal" content in that div. This can be pre-loaded, or you can demand-load JavaScript and other resources to fill it.
- Have a UI control of some sort on the `div` that "closes" it by removing the `div` and hiding the `iframe`.

You can build very rich UIs with this that (can) have a dramatically better UX than enforced multiple windows. And you have the advantage of avoiding cross-windows communication and potentially offering much better response time to the user when they "open" one of these windows.